# ¿Como utilizar traits en Laravel 5.4.18?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Dónde crear exactamente el archivo, qué escribir en el mismo, y cómo utilizar las funciones declaradas en el trait. **Utilizo Laravel Framework 5.4.18**

*-No he alterado ninguna carpeta del framework, todo esta en donde corresponde-*

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un trait no es más que otra funcionalidad de PHP, no tiene nada que ver con Laravel o algún otro Framework: http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php

Respondiendo a las preguntas:

> ¿Cómo utilizar traits en Laravel?

Igual a como se utilizarían en PHP "puro".

> ¿Dónde crear exactamente el archivo?

Probablemente en la carpeta `app/` en la subcarpeta que consideres conveniente según el diseño de tu aplicación.

> ¿Qué escribir en el mismo?

Lo mismo que escribirías en cualquier otro trait, sin olvidar el namespace correspondiente.

> ¿Cómo utilizar las funciones declaradas en el trait?

De la misma forma que las utilizarías en cualquier otro proyecto PHP.